# rotating icons without using two different layouts

Tags: android, android-layout, rotation, icons

I am trying to implement icon rotation when the user rotates the phone from portrait position to landscape and vice versa. One way of doing this is to create two separate layouts (.xml) one for portrait mode and one for landscape mode and in each of them have appropriate rotated icons.

But this is not a clean solution and causes a view jump when the user rotates from one orientation to the other.

Is there a way to be able just to rotate icons without using two different layouts?

Comment: `... this is not a clean solution ...` It's indeed the **cleanest** solution.

Comment: Are you saying this is the best solution to use two different layouts? but I see a jump in the view when I rotate the phone.

Comment: This is the way Google thought it has to be. And it's very straigthforward. If it's the best or not, this has to be tested and compared to some other "less clean" solution.

Comment: Can you please point to some "less clean" solutions?

Comment: No. I should take time to design some custom component or to handle the rotation changes some how. Which I'm too lazy to do.

Answer (score 0):

Get [OrientationEventListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/OrientationEventListener) with related orientation. Create an observer that emits those events to any view(ImageView). Stay more generic if you want to precise this logic to your layout system. Perform an animation e.g.: `yourImageView.animate().rotation(anyDegree).start()`. Be aware of the life cycles after orientation changes.

For accuracy [SensorEventListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEventListener) might also be possible but it's a bit overhead.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, can you make your answer more complete with a working code?